I am trying to migrate my supabase database but I am receiving Missing script error

Below Is my db.ts snippet.
    import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js';
    import postgres from 'postgres';
    import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
    import * as schema from '../../../migrations/schema';
    import { migrate } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js/migrator';
    
    dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });
    
    if (!process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
      console.log(' no database URL');
    }
    
    const client = postgres(process.env.DATABASE_URL as string, { max: 1 });
    const db = drizzle(client, { schema });
    
    const migrateDb = async () => {
      try {
        console.log(' Migrating client');
        await migrate(db, { migrationsFolder: 'migrations' });
        console.log(' Successfully Migrated');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(' Error Migrating client', error);
      }
    };
    migrateDb();
    export default db;

and here are my scripts.
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "push": "drizzle-kit push:pg",
    "pull": "drizzle-kit introspect:pg ",
    "generate": "drizzle-kit generate:pg",
    "drop": "drizzle-kit drop",
    "check": "drizzle-kit check:pg",
    "up": "drizzle-kit up:pg",
    "migrate": "npm  run src/lib/supabase/db.ts"

  },

How do I fix the error in order to migrate my database.

If both db connection is working properly, then please create proper schema for data migration.
May be some schema conversion having some issue.
Frist check is your source database/s data is fetching properly or not..
If it works, then check your target db schema ...
